# how to make image as clickable to submit image id to a php file?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have something like this

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    $i=0;
    while($i<3){
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
        echo '<div class="panel-body"><img src="';
        echo $row['imageurl'];
        echo '"class="img-responsive" style="width:250px" style="height:250px" alt="Image"></div>';
        echo '<div class="panel-footer">';
        echo $row['name'];
        echo '</div></div></div>';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I want to click the image so that it calls a new PHP file with the image id.
To view the output http://csedu.cf/test.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your image tag in `a` tag.

```
while($i<3)
        {
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
                echo '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
                echo '<div class="panel-body"><a href="test.php?id=image_id"><img src="';
                echo $row['imageurl'];
                echo '"class="img-responsive" style="width:250px" style="height:250px" alt="Image"></div>';
                echo '</a><div class="panel-footer">';
                echo $row['name'];
                echo '</div></div></div>';
                $i++;
        }
```